# What is the system data used in"Include system data" in android error reports?

Tags: android, error-reporting

Android 2.2 has a new feature,in which when something unexpected happens in an application, the system send a error message asking the user to either `"Force close"` the app or `"Report"` the error to the developer.

Now when the user selects `"Report"` there is a checkbox asking him to `"Include system data"` and then send the report.

So does somebody know what system data is included in the error report sent to the developer?

Comment: yes it includes only the device information ans error logs.

Comment: and my another question is that is this system information sent to Google or developer?

Comment: @AliImran:okay it includes error logs, but what device information is included?i want specific answers.

Comment: it contains device model. OS version , screen DPI, and size in pixels etc

Comment: @AliImran:thanks man for the info,your help is appreciated. Anyone else out there who knows more on this topic?